# how to get user selected scheme when running gym script in fastlane?

Tags: ios, fastlane

I've added fastlane to my iOS project to create .ipa

with the following script i can create ipa.

```
  desc "Generate .ipa"
  lane :createipa do
    gym(clean: true, export_method: ENV["EXPORT_METHOD"], output_directory: ENV["DIRECTORY"])
  end
```

there are 2 other properties for gym, one is **scheme** which is related to different schemes and the one you want create ipa from, and the other is **output_name** which is the name of the ipa.
now, when i use this script without scheme, it asked me in runtime to choose the scheme, i want to save the **user input scheme** in runtime to a variable and set it as **output_name**, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for user input, why don't you just pass the scheme name to the script when you run `fastlane`? Like so:

`bundle exec fastlane createipa scheme:MySchemeName`

And modify your `Fastfile` to be:

```
  desc "Generate .ipa"
    lane :createipa do |options|
      gym(
        clean: true,
        export_method: ENV["EXPORT_METHOD"],
        output_directory: ENV["DIRECTORY"],
        scheme: options[:scheme]
      )
    end
```

Or, you could save it as an `ENV` entry:

`XCODE_SCHEME=MySchemeName bundle exec fastlane`

**To answer the question directly, use this code**

```ruby
desc 'Generate the ipa based on the scheme selected by the user'
lane :createipa do
  glob_pattern = 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj/**/*.xcscheme'
  schemes = Dir[glob_pattern].map do |scheme_filepath|
    File.basename(scheme_filepath)
  end
  prompt_text = 'Select a scheme:\n'
  schemes.each_index do |index|
    prompt_text << "  #{index}. #{schemes[index]}\n"
  end
  prompt_text << '> '
  print prompt_text
  selected_scheme_index = gets.to_i
  selected_scheme = schemes[selected_scheme_index]
  puts "Selected Scheme: #{selected_scheme}"

  ipa_output_name "#{selected_scheme}.ipa"

  gym(
    clean: true,
    export_method: ENV['EXPORT_METHOD'],
    output_directory: ENV['DIRECTORY'],
    scheme: selected_scheme,
    output_name: ipa_output_name
  )
end
```

Comment: _personally_, I would prefer passing all those parameters in the same way. Either as options to the lane, or all as `ENV` entries.

Comment: well, the problem is that i don't know the scheme name, so i can't add it after  ```fastlane createipa```. when i run ```fastlane createipa```, because i didn't select the scheme, it shows me the list of schemes and ask me to choose one, that's where i want to say the user input and put it as **output_name***

Comment: I'm confused. You can easily look at the schemes by opening Xcode and looking at the schemes, or navigating into the project bundle `MyProject.xcodeproj/xcsharedata/xcschemes/SchemeName.xcscheme` (or, instead of `xcshareddata`, `xcuserdata`). Can you elaborate on why you won't know what the scheme is when you run the command? If I understand what the problem is, I can help you.

Comment: sure, that's because i have only one file for all my projects, which has different schemes with different names, and i want to have a general FastFile and add it to all my projects. is it clear? i can explain more. thanks for your time and help.

Comment: That helps a little. So, you're looking to automatically create an ipa for each project. The scheme names that you want to use to create the ipa are different for each project. Yes?

Comment: yes, exactly, and i want the spa name be the scheme name.

Comment: When you run `fastlane` are you running it from the command line, such as `bundle exec fastlane createipa`? Can you walk me through how you expect it to be used?

Comment: yes, i run it from the command line, and after i write ```fast lane createipa``` it shows me the list of the schemes of the project and asks me to choose one of them. in this place i want to save the selected scheme's name in a variable and set it as spa name.

Comment: So, I still do not understand why you cannot just provide the Scheme name yourself if you are the one running the command. Perhaps there is some reason why you don't want to explain the process. In which case I'll make the brute force suggestion.

Comment: I'm not the only one who has gonna so this. And it's not only for my project, i want to have a general fastfile for all the projects in my company, so every one can use it without any changes.

Comment: Do you have _many_ projects? Or, many Schemes? Or both? That sounds like a lot. I hope the above answer helps.

Comment: i have a lot of projects, and each project has 4 schemes with at least 2 contributer,
i will check your answer as soon as possible, thanks for following up.

Comment: My solution was for **1** project. You may need to add another step to also ask from which Project the developer wants an ipa.