# Fastlane get all scheme and configurations of iOS Project

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-gym, fastlane-pilot

Im trying to build a lane that generates build for my iOS project. I needed to build an app version for every scheme and configuration that I have added. Now I can iterate through the configurations using the following:

```
 project.targets.each do |mtarget|
        if mtarget.name == target
            mtarget.build_configurations.each do |mbuild|
                UI.error "Configuration #{mbuild}"
                if mbuild.name == buildConfiguration
                    app_identifier = mbuild.build_settings['PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER']
                end
            end

        end
    end
```

Now I want to be able to get all the schemes and configurations so that I can build_app for all schemes with params:

```
build_app(scheme:<schemeHere>, configuration: <configHere>, workspace: <...)
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I can list all of the schemes file path, thanks to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644139/how-to-get-user-selected-scheme-when-running-gym-script-in-fastlane). What remains is how to get file name and how to match them a configuration.

```
##GETTING ALL SCHEMES
glob_pattern = "#{project.path}/**/*.xcscheme"
schemes = Dir[glob_pattern].map do |scheme_filename|
       File.basename(scheme_filename)
end

schemes.each_index do |index|
       UI.message "  #{index}. #{schemes[index]}\n"
       build_app(scheme: "#{schemes[index]}", workspace: './ios/Project.xcworkspace', export_method: 'app-store')
end
```